# reading csv file to pandas dataframe as float

Tags: python, csv, pandas, parsing

I have a `.csv` file with strings in the top row and first column, with the rest of the data as floating point numbers. I want to read it into a dataframe with the first row and column as column names and index respectively, and all the floating values as `float64`.

If I use `df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0)` all the numeric values are left as strings.

If I use `df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, dtype=np.float64)` I get an exception: `ValueError: could not convert string to float` as it attempts to parse the first column as `float`.

There are a large number of columns, and i do not have the column names, so I don't want to identify each column for parsing as `float`; I want to parse every column *except* the first one.

Comment: What is the format of your numbers? I'm pretty sure pandas will infer the dtypes without any arguments. Have you tried that? What was the result?

Comment: I will post some example data....

Comment: `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` You can convert the values after you have the dataFrame,

Comment: I have found a single row in the .csv which has non-numeric data in it, so the whole column is parsed as a string. Thank you juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code was correct

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0)
```

but the `.csv` file had been constructed incorrectly.

As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, pandas will infer the `dtypes` without any arguments, provided all the data in a column is of the same `dtype`. The columns were being interpreted as strings because although *most* of the data was numeric, one row contained non-numeric data (actually dates). Removing this row from the `.csv` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Get the list of all column names, remove the first one. cast other columns.

```
cols = df.columns
cols.remove('fistcolumn')
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```